# query run successful but database not updated java

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to add `Insert`query in a database. everything is working fine and I'm not getting any error. But data which I inserted in a database is not reflected on a database. In sort, Database is not updated.

```
  try{
    Database_Operation db = new Database_Operation();

    db.connection();

    db.cn.setAutoCommit(false);
    db.cn.commit();
    PreparedStatement  ps1=db.cn.prepareStatement("insert into product values(?,?,?)");



    Boolean status = true;

    ps1.setString(1,name.getText());
    ps1.setString(2, price.getText());
    ps1.setString(3, status.toString());

    db.cn.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," Data saved ", "succsess" ,1);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You forget to execute the query **and** you should commit afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `execution` statement. Add following line before `DB` close.

```
ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: DML statements need to be run through `executeUpdate()` not through `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

Your execution statement is si missing.
You're just forming the query and not executing it.

Before closing your db connection, add this line to your code:

```
ps1.executeUpdate;
```

Comment: DML statements need to be run through `executeUpdate()` not through `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

You must have an execution method in Database_Operation and execute then just after the initialisation of the prepareStatement like this:

```
try {


    // execute update SQL stetement
    ps1.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("Record is updated to DBUSER table!");

} catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't execute the PreparedStatement.Add the below line ps1.execute();

```
 try{
    Database_Operation db = new Database_Operation();

    db.connection();

    db.cn.setAutoCommit(false);
    db.cn.commit();
    PreparedStatement  ps1=db.cn.prepareStatement("insert into product values(?,?,?)");



    Boolean status = true;

    ps1.setString(1,name.getText());
    ps1.setString(2, price.getText());
    ps1.setString(3, status.toString());
    ps1.execute();
    db.cn.close();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," Data saved ", "succsess" ,1);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```